# Monitoring Events in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

When I look in the AWS console under Lambda -> Metrics, I see a graph depicting lambda invocations. There is a strange repetitive pattern I see occurring daily involving a rapid spike of invocations at the same times each day (costing $$). So it seems lambda has been configured somewhere to trigger regularly.

Where in the AWS console can I actually delve into the details/body of the events that are occurring over a specific time period so that I may backtrack and correct the issue? (These are RDS events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add some logging to the Lambda function (if you haven't already) to log the entire Context and Event objects at the start of each invocation. Then check the CloudWatch Logs for this function after another spike to see what exactly was in the Context and Event objects during that spike. That should give you the information you need to see what is prompting the spike in invocations.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Mark